# Post request works fine in Postman and Insomnia, but not in JS code

Tags: javascript, post, axios, postman, insomnia

I've been trying to get this post request to work for a few days now, but it doesn't matter what I change, it never works.
This is the JS code that I'm using:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://[DOMAIN]/datanew.php?sto=0",
    data: {
        aktion:"getstdpl",
        sid:0,
        ignore:1
    },
    headers: {
        "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=ad4aaf7f7a5...",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.data)
    //console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I have tried the same request in both Insomnia and Postman and it works fine in both, but using my provided JS code, I just get no output at all. Not even an error.
After failing to get a satisfying result in JS I also tried to use Java, but that gave me the same result as JS.

Comment: Try with node-fetch. I dropped Axios a few weeks ago because I had too many issues with it.

Comment: @JeremyThille Ok I switched to node-fetch, but it still returns an empty string.
Heres my code: https://hastebin.com/neqofiveji.less

Comment: Ah, in this case I'm afraid I'm out of options :/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are limited by Same Origin Policy in what they can read or write. In particular, browsers' code loaded from one origin is not allowed to set cookies designated for another origin.